Hardhat - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') error in event log
I wanted to study the events on hardhat by following this lesson.
npx version: 9.5.1
node version: v12.22.9
Here's my contract code:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract SimpleStorage {

    uint256 favoriteNumber;
    event storedNumber(
        uint256 indexed oldNumber,
        uint256 indexed newNumber,
        uint256 addedNumber,
        address sender
    );

    function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        emit storedNumber(
            favoriteNumber,
            _favoriteNumber,
            _favoriteNumber + favoriteNumber,
            msg.sender
        );
        favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
    }

    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256) {
        return favoriteNumber;
    }
}

Here's my script:
deploy_and_store.js
async function main() {

    await hre.run("compile");

      // We get the contract to deploy
    const SimpleStorage = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("SimpleStorage");
    const simpleStorage = await SimpleStorage.deploy();
    await simpleStorage.waitForDeployment();

    const transactionResponse = await simpleStorage.store(1);
    const transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait();
    console.log(transactionReceipt);
    console.log(transactionReceipt.events[0]);
    
}

main().catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
    process.exitCode = 1
  })

When I execute the command:
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy_and_store.js 

The output of console.log(transactionReceipt); is:
ContractTransactionReceipt {
  provider: HardhatEthersProvider {
    _hardhatProvider: LazyInitializationProviderAdapter {
      _providerFactory: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
      _emitter: [EventEmitter],
      _initializingPromise: [Promise],
      provider: [BackwardsCompatibilityProviderAdapter]
    },
    _networkName: 'hardhat',
    _blockListeners: [],
    _transactionHashListeners: Map(0) {},
    _eventListeners: []
  },
  to: '0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3',
  from: '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266',
  contractAddress: null,
  hash: '0x6c7f5c327bda60c98ec15ac8a4911f48e8cac977f9fb94d7e89871f08933a05d',
  index: 0,
  blockHash: '0xf64f2050788f46fb3064a709a1cfffac792dbabcfcf0388583f048507d868963',
  blockNumber: 2,
  logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000040020000000000000000000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000060000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000',
  gasUsed: 46372n,
  blobGasUsed: undefined,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 46372n,
  gasPrice: 1767032241n,
  blobGasPrice: undefined,
  type: 2,
  status: 1,
  root: undefined
}

and the output of console.log(transactionReceipt.events[0]); is:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at main (..\scripts\deploy_and_store.js:19:42)

means that I can't see the event.
Can someone tell me where I'm wrong?
Thank you very much.
Best regards!

Instead of events, it should be the logs array, inside the transactionReceipt object.
So, replace this:
console.log(transactionReceipt.events[0]);

with:
console.log(transactionReceipt.logs[0]);


hy Syed, thank you very much. it works perfectly.
